# How does bash interpret the equal operator with no surrounding spaces in a conditional?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

The following script does not behave as I would have expected.  Adding spaces around the '=' in the conditional made it perform how I wanted, but it got me thinking, what is it actually doing inside the conditional?

```
#!/bin/bash
S1='foo'
S2='bar'
if [ $S1=$S2 ];
then
    echo "S1('$S1') is equal to S2('$S2')
fi
echo $S1
echo $S2
```

The output is:

```
S1('foo') is equal to S2('bar')
foo
bar
```

The contents of S1 and S2 don't change from what they are assigned, so the = doesn't perform an assignment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's helpful to remember that `[` is actually a command, also available as `test`. In bash like in most other Bourne-like shells, it's a builtin command, so you can see the documentation with `info bash [` or by searching inside `man bash` (also `man builtin` on some systems where bash is also the system's `sh`).

In that documentation:

> `test` and `[` evaluate conditional expressions using a set of rules
> based on the number of arguments.
>
> - 0 arguments
>   The expression is false.
> - 1 argument
>   The expression is true if and only if the argument is not
>   null.
> - 2 arguments
>   [...]
> - 3 arguments
>   [...]

Pedantically speaking, when using `[` instead of `test` for the command, the final (required) `]` is *also* an argument, but that's not counted in the numbers above (which come straight from the bash documentation). Anyway...

The two-argument rules are various tests, and the three-argument ones are generally comparisons. When you put a space around the `=`, you get three arguments. But when you put it all together, you get *one* argument, and as you can see, if that argument isn't null, it returns true.

Well, technically, since you forgot the quotes around the parameter expansions in `[ $S1=$S2 ]` (and everywhere else), `$S1` and `$S2` are subject to split+glob, so that could result in more arguments passed to the `[` command. In bash, like in ksh, that would even constitute a command injection vulnerability.

For instance, if `$S1` was defined as `S1='-v xx[$(reboot)] -o yy'` and `$S2` as `S2='zz'`, the splitting part, with the default value of `$IFS` would yield `-v`, `xx[$(reboot)]`, `-o`, `yy=zz`; `[...]` being a globbing operator the `xx[$(reboot)]` could expand to `xxo`, `xxt` if there were such files in the current directory, but if not, `xx[$(reboot)]` would be passed as-is to `[` and `-v array[index]` in bash's `[` builtin is a test to check whether the array element is set, and `$(reboot)` would be expanded to the output of the `reboot` command to determine the index.

The correct syntax is `[ "$S1" = "$S2" ]`, where it's also critical not to forget the quotes.

Answer (score 5):

The equals operator does nothing in this case.

The expression `$S1=$S2` evaluates to an actual string, with the values of `S1` and `S2` in place, effectively the string literal `foo=bar`.

Since this string literal is not null, the statement

```
if [ "foo=bar" ];
```

evaluates to true, and the body of the if statement is executed.

Comment: I figured this one out right before submitting the question, but as the atmosphere of stackexchange is one of learning, I thought I may as well add my question and answer to the pool of knowledge that is stackexchange, rather than just discarding it.

Comment: And what you're looking for is in fact `[ "$S1" = "$S2" ]`. Otherwise, if `$S1` or `$S2` contain wildcard or spaces, they would be expanded (e.g. try both with `S1='a = a -o a'` and `S2='b'`). In ksh, bash and zsh, you can use `[[ $S1 = $S2 ]]`, because `[[`…`]]` is special shell syntax whereas `[` is an ordinary command with a funny name. Note that you also need spaces around the brackets in either case.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', in bash, like in ksh, that should be `[[ "$S1" = "$S2" ]]` or at least `[[ $S1 = "$S2" ]]`. `[[ $S1 = $S2 ]]` is a test of whether the contents of `$S1` matches the pattern stored in `$S2`. For instance, `S1='[x]'; [[ $S1 = $S1 ]]` returns false because `[x]` doesn't match the `[x]` pattern. Quoting `$S2` causes the contents to be take literally, not as a pattern.