# To what does an unquoted empty variable expand in bash?

Tags: bash, quoting

To what value does an unquoted, undeclared variable expand to in order to return an exit status of `0`?

Here is an example of a particular situation I ran into:

```
[ -n $var ]; echo $?
0

[ -n "$var" ]; echo $?
1
```

In both tests, the variable `var` is not declared.
I could have saved me the hassle by testing with `-z`, where quoted or unquoted apparently doesn't make a difference, but I ran into this particular situation and I started wondering. I looked deeper into all the expansions that bash performs, but couldn't find any explanation for this behavior.

As a general rule I usually quote variables, but hopefully the reason of this behavior helps me better understand quoting.

Comment: `[ -n ]` is true (0) since `-n` is a non-empty string.  Also note that `[ -z $var ]` would have been true for the same reason.  I suspect there would be a duplicate question for this somewhere...

Comment: In your case, you can do without the option `-n`: `[ "$var" ]` or `[ $var ]`

Comment: Related: [How does bash interpret the equal operator with no surrounding spaces in a conditional?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7655/how-does-bash-interpret-the-equal-operator-with-no-surrounding-spaces-in-a-condi)

Comment: @nezabudka, no, please don't tell people to use (the unquoted) `[ $var ]`, it breaks the moment `$var` contains more than one word

Comment: On the other hand, `[ -z $var ]` works quoted or not as long as `$var` contains one or zero words. I think there was a post explaining that somewhere, but I can't find it so I'll leave this as an exercise...

Comment: @ikkachu, Will it be okay?: `[ -n $var ]` or `[ -z $var ]`.  "In your case...". Considering a certain example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `test`, `[` and `[[` commands all act the same in that
they do different things based on *how many arguments they are given*
(excluding the closing `]`/`]]`).

- with 1 argument, the test will be successful if the argument is not empty
- with 2 arguments, the arguments are treated as a unary operator (such as
  `-n`) and an operand.
- with 3 arguments, the arguments are treated as an operand, a binary
  operator (such as `=`) and another operand
- more than 3 arguments, `test` and `[` give a "too many arguments" error,
  and `[[` may give a different error (it has a more complicated parser).

Now, looking at the `[ -n $var ]` example, and comparing against the `[[` construct. Since `[[` does not do **word splitting**, it knows where variable values are.
When `var=""`, given `[[ -n $var ]]`, after parameter expansion, bash will see `[[ -n "" ]]` which is clearly **false**.

But for `test` and `[`, word splitting is in effect. So `[ -n $var ]`
becomes `[ -n  ]` (the empty string disappears). Now, `[` sees one
argument *which is a non-empty string*, and is therefore **true**.

If you quote the variable: `[ -n "$var" ]`, then you'll get the
expected false result.

Comment: There are similar confusing results when `var='*'` due to filename expansion.

Comment: Thanks, helpful! Also because you indicate that the test behaves differently depending on the number of arguments.

Comment: Also, refer to the canonical Q&A [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667) for ALL the details.