# Grep command not returning expected results for testing

Tags: bash, shell, test

I am attempting to do a comparison before I append conditions to a profile.d file

A `grep -F 'TMOUT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local` shows me exactly what I expect however the test is always showing true. In all of these examples I've already appended the information I want to sh.local but I don't want to do it again if it is present.

```
[ ! `grep -Fq 'TMOUT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local` ] && echo $?
0
[ ! `grep -Fq 'NOT_PRESENT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local` ] && echo $?
0
```

Although this is for an .ebextension command the tests are failing before I even try to deploy, I imagine the final result should look like this but I'm obviously wrong about something. I've tried using $(grep) vs `grep`. Also ==1 vs !

```yaml
  01_hard_5.4.5_shell_timeout:
    test: "[ $(grep -Fxq 'TMOUT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local) ==1 ]"
    command: |
      printf '\nTMOUT=300\nreadonly TMOUT\nexport TMOUT\n' | sudo tee -a /etc/profile.d/sh.local >/dev/null
```

And for the record this is Amazon Linux 2 and the following commands spit out the following

```bsh
grep -F 'TMOUT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local
TMOUT=300
readonly TMOUT
export TMOUT

grep -F 'NOT_PRESENT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local
```

Comment: Just do `grep -Fq ... || echo stuff_to_add`

Comment: Note that bash is a very whitespace-sensitive language: `==1` is NOT the same as `== 1`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In

```
[ ! `grep -Fq 'TMOUT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local` ] && echo $?
0
[ ! `grep -Fq 'NOT_PRESENT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local` ] && echo $?
0
```

the backticks around the grep command constitute a *command substitution*, returning the command's standard output. Since you used `-q`, standard output is always empty so regardless of what string you grep for, your `[ ! ... ]` tests both become

```
[ ! ]
```

This is the "one argument form" of the test construct, and tests the non-emptiness of the one-character string `!` - which is always true.

To test the *exit status* of the grep commands you may use:

```
grep -Fq 'TMOUT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local && echo $?
```

See also

- [To what does an unquoted empty variable expand in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615658/to-what-does-an-unquoted-empty-variable-expand-in-bash)

---

Likewise,

```
[ $(grep -Fxq 'TMOUT' /etc/profile.d/sh.local) ==1 ]
```

becomes

```
[ ==1 ]
```

which tests the non-emptiness of string `==1`; you probably intended to write `== 1` which would at least have errored out with message `[: ==: unary operator expected` - see

- [Why are bash tests so picky about whitespace?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117438/why-are-bash-tests-so-picky-about-whitespace)

Comment: Since this is `[` not `[[`, then the absence of quotes is important. The output of the command substitution is empty, so the test becomes `[ ! ]` -- now that `[` only receives one argument, the test becomes: is "!" non-empty? A one-character string is always non-empty, so the test is always true.

Comment: @glennjackman oops thanks ... will update